# Loopback connections not working on Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, loopback

I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7. My MVC application runs fine on asp.net 4.5 version. Note that application works fine on other servers and hosting accounts.

However, on one of the new system... only one of the function is not working and I'm getting an error trying to run another function from application by making an http call!

This works fine on other all other hosting accounts (on different server) / on shared server too and development machine. Not sure why on this new windows 2008 server with IIS its not working.

I am getting (404) Not Found error when application tries to call this URL.

If I call the function manually, it runs.. but I need to call this function in certain event by making an http call within application. This is a loopback connection originating from application to the same application but another function called at different url with parameters.

Can anyone advise what could be wrong here? And what thing we need to fix to enable loopback connections support in IIS / server?

Here is the code that is used.

```
HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
objRequest.Method = "GET";
objRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
objRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
```

Awaiting your quick response on the same.

Comment: Please post the code you're using to make this 'loopback' request.

Comment: Also, having to make a HTTP request *to itself* just sounds like a bad design. Why can't you call the processing method directly, or are you using the ASP.NET runtime to generate HTML for you to process internally? If that's the case, please note you can use view-engines to render data without needing another HTTP context.

Comment: Finally, you might be hitting problems where webhosts prevent any websites they're hosting from making outbound connections (even to themselves), this is done to minimize security risks and stop their websites from being used to launch DDOS attacks, for example.

Comment: @Dai added the code into the question. Please have a look and advise. The problem is.. it works on all other installations and not working on this one new VPS server. Is there any configuration related things that needs to be changed in IIS / Windows Server?

Comment: If you're getting HTTP 404 you're probably connecting to the wrong website. Ensure your website site bindings in IIS are correct.

Comment: Hi, it is the same application. I can access website and everything else is working fine. So I suppose that bindings in IIS are correct. What else could be wrong here?

Comment: Look at your IIS access logs to see where the request is being made. I still don't think your application is receiving the request.

Comment: Can you show us the value of the `url` parameter for the failing request? Also, I see that you are setting `ContentType` for a `GET` request. `GET` requests cannot have content.

Comment: Hi, Here is the sample URL example.com/Admin/module/actionname?key=abcd&store=1 We will remove Content Type from get request, but that doesn't fix this issue!

Comment: In your URL example, what does "example.com" translate to, loadbalancer IP, machine extern IP, loopback 127.0.0.1?  If not the later, does it work if you make request to 127.0.0.1/Admin/module/actionname?key=abcd&store=1  ?

Comment: I have 401 authentication errors having to do with loopback web requests before http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861 This is not a 404 error but you can try the setups mentioned in this article to see if it helps. Also I have run into 404 errors if any url rewrite rules were setup that were wrong and then fixed, but I had to clear the browser cache even after the url rewrite rule was corrected.

Comment: Hi, The bindings are correct and the site is working fine except this particular request URL. the example.com is website binding to the port 80. There is no load balancer in between.

Comment: I found that when I access website from domain name on local server it was not served correctly. So I created an entry to resolve domain to 127.0.0.1 and then it seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the mapping of the domain in Server. When trying to open the domain from external network, it serves the website correctly. But when I tried to open on the browser on the same server it wasn't serving the request.

I added the domain name entry to the windows hosts file and resolved it to 127.0.0.1, then it started to work fine.

Thank you everyone for your efforts in helping me fixing the issue. Without your inputs I might not be able to fix this. The credit is all yours, but as there was no answer I created an answer for helping other who faces same issue.